# How to convert an array into key-value pair array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am having this array :

```
array(
    0 => array("name", "address", "city"), 
    1=> array( "anoop", "palasis", "Indore"),
    2=> array( "ravinder", "annapurna", "Indore")
)
```

and i want to make this array in this way :

```
array( 
    0 =>  array("name" = >"anoop" , "address" = >"palasia", "city" = >"Indore"),
    1 =>  array("name" = >"ravinder" , "address" = >"annapurna", "city" = >"Indore")
)
```

Comment: Please indicate in your question that (if) you want to use the items in the first element as keys.

Comment: i want to make that array into key-value pair... please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine). If `$array` contains your data

```
$result = array(
             array_combine($array[0], $array[1]),
             array_combine($array[0], $array[2])
          );
```

In general

```
$result = array();
$len = count($array);
for($i=1;$i<$len; $i++){
    $result[] = array_combine($array[0], $array[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The modern way is:

```
$data = array_column($data, 'value', 'key');
```

In your case:

```
$data = array_column($data, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data are in `$array`:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array[0]); $i++) {
        $res[$array[0][$i]] = $value[$i];
    }
}
```

The result is now in `$res`.

Comment: -1 for executing `count()` for every iteration of not only the inner `for` loop, but also the outer `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Phoenix Does efficiency even matter here at all? Are you serious?

Comment: It's a bad practice.  The array that is presented in the OP has 2 rows to process, but the array may have been truncated for posting here; it might actually hold thousands of records.  Or someone might come across this answer while solving a similar problem and pick up a bad habit.

Comment: @Phoenix No, it's counting the length of the *first row*. Which is like five elements long, and is never going to be "thousands". Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: The `count` in `for` loop is so well known bad practice that it tempts to down vote as soon as you see it. I down voted. Then canceled. :(

Comment: @Borealid That's a fair point.  However, I still stand by my -1.  Outside of very unusual circumstances, there is no good reason to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that you can use:

```
function rewrap(Array $input){
    $key_names = array_shift($input);
    $output = Array();
    foreach($input as $index => $inner_array){
        $output[] = array_combine($key_names,$inner_array);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Here is a demonstration:

```
// Include the function from above here 
$start = array(
    0 => array("name", "address", "city"),
    1 => array("anoop", "palasis", "Indore"),
    2 => array("ravinder", "annapurna", "Indore")
);
print_r(rewrap($start));
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => anoop
            [address] => palasis
            [city] => Indore
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ravinder
            [address] => annapurna
            [city] => Indore
        )

)
```

**Note:** Your first array defined index `1` twice, so I changed the second one to `2`, like this:

```
array(0 => array("name", "address", "city"), 1 => array("anoop", "palasis", "Indore"),2 => array("ravinder", "annapurna", "Indore"))
```

That was probably just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are parsing a CSV file, check out the answers to this question:

> [Get associative array from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358233/get-associative-array-from-csv)

Comment: Either close vote or comment. It can not be answer.[should-we-flag-answers-that-only-contain-a-link-to-another-so-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95491/should-we-flag-answers-that-only-contain-a-link-to-another-so-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I have read the discussion. However, I do not agree, and think there is some added value in linking to a question that refers to the concept of an *associative array*, not mentioned before by the OP.